# PHP7.2 crash with php7.2-mbstring

Tags: php

I  caught mistake with php vars

```
php_admin_value[mbstring.func_overload] = 2
```

But wihout this options its all right!
But I am needing this option!!!

```
[01-Dec-2017 13:42:12] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10997
[01-Dec-2017 13:42:12] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[01-Dec-2017 13:42:12] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[01-Dec-2017 13:43:25] WARNING: [pool www] child 10999 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 73.0072
08 seconds from start
[01-Dec-2017 13:43:25] NOTICE: [pool www] child 11470 started
[01-Dec-2017 13:43:29] WARNING: [pool www] child 10998 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 76.4018
86 seconds from start
```

php-mbstring version

```
Package: php7.2-mbstring
Version: 7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

php version

```
PHP 7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2017     13:58:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologie
```

My including extensions

> /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/opcache.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xml.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/calendar.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ctype.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/curl.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/dom.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/exif.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/fileinfo.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ftp.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/gd.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/gettext.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/iconv.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/igbinary.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/imagick.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/json.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/ldap.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mbstring.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqli.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/phar.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/posix.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/readline.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/redis.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/shmop.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/simplexml.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/soap.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sockets.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvsem.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sysvshm.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/tokenizer.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/wddx.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xmlreader.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xmlwriter.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xsl.ini
>   /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/zip.ini

Please! Help me!

Comment: This options has been [deprecated](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php). Even if you get it to work now, it will be removed in a future PHP version. You should find a way to remove your reliance on it.

Comment: Thank for you very match! I mast remove functional, where I use this extension on my project?